# Tableview throws index out of bounds exception when item selected

Tags: exception, javafx, tableview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a JavaFX tableview. When I click on a row, I receive an exception. The exception provides no pointers to my code to indicate where my error may lie.

This is the selectedItem property listener:

```
orderTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) orderSelected();
        });
```

The exception occurs after the listener completes. I've been unable to figure out why an index out of bounds exception is generated merely by selecting a valid, visible item from the table.

The exception is:

```
08-01-18 21:31:12.871 ERROR java.lang.Throwable - Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
08-01-18 21:31:12.874 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
08-01-18 21:31:12.875 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
08-01-18 21:31:12.876 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.handleSelectedCellsListChangeEvent(TableView.java:3004)
08-01-18 21:31:12.876 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2423)
08-01-18 21:31:12.876 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:1914)
08-01-18 21:31:12.876 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:215)
08-01-18 21:31:12.876 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:148)
08-01-18 21:31:12.877 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
08-01-18 21:31:12.877 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
08-01-18 21:31:12.878 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
08-01-18 21:31:12.878 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
08-01-18 21:31:12.878 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
08-01-18 21:31:12.878 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
08-01-18 21:31:12.879 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
08-01-18 21:31:12.879 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
08-01-18 21:31:12.879 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
08-01-18 21:31:12.879 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.880 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
08-01-18 21:31:12.880 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.880 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
08-01-18 21:31:12.881 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.881 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
08-01-18 21:31:12.881 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.881 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
08-01-18 21:31:12.881 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.882 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
08-01-18 21:31:12.882 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
08-01-18 21:31:12.883 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
08-01-18 21:31:12.883 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
08-01-18 21:31:12.883 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
08-01-18 21:31:12.883 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
08-01-18 21:31:12.884 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
08-01-18 21:31:12.884 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
08-01-18 21:31:12.884 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
08-01-18 21:31:12.885 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
08-01-18 21:31:12.885 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
08-01-18 21:31:12.885 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
08-01-18 21:31:12.885 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
08-01-18 21:31:12.885 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
08-01-18 21:31:12.886 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
08-01-18 21:31:12.886 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
08-01-18 21:31:12.886 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
08-01-18 21:31:12.886 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
08-01-18 21:31:12.887 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
08-01-18 21:31:12.888 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] that reproduces the same error? Are you doing any multithreading in the application?

Comment: What does `orderSelected()` do? If it modifies the `items` or the selection somehow this could lead to the error, since JavaFX expects the properties not to be modified during the listener's execution.

Comment: @James_D I wish I could produce an example as you request, but I've been unable to. Similar classes elsewhere in my program do not display this error, nor have I been able to narrow down further what parts of my code are responsible for this.
The application is single threaded.

Comment: @fabian orderSelected copies information from the selected PurchaseOrder into various textfields and comboboxes. It makes no changes to the list, nor to the attributes within the time the listener is active.

Comment: So are you using background threads anywhere in your code? The only way I can reproduce this error is by updating a table's backing list from the wrong thread.

Comment: I appreciate your attempting this. The application runs entirely in a single thread.

Comment: @James_D ...unless JavaFX is using multithreads behind the scenes. My code does not modify the list.

Comment: You must be modifying the list *somewhere* (else there would be nothing in the table). I'm pretty sure you must be changing the content of the table from a thread other than the FX Application Thread to get this error. (Or, possibly, violating the "don't modify a list while its changes are being processed" rule, as fabian suggests: but I think you would have a different stack trace for that). If you can't reproduce this in an example, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem while attempting to provide a "minimal, complete and verifiable" example.

The table selection listener called orderSelected():

```
    private void orderSelected() {
             clear();
             currentPurchaseOrder = orderTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
             soldToCombo.getSelectionModel().select(currentPurchaseOrder.getCustomer());
...


private void clear() {
         currentPurchaseOrder = null;
         orderTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

After clear(), any operation that updated the table (including a screen refresh) would throw the exception.